# Can I disable escaping in $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending an escaped JSON response like this (if I open the response directly):

```
{"htmlcode":"\u003cspan\u003eabc\u003c/span\u003e Test"}
```

but the $.ajax() method gives the result object back as:

```
htmlcode: "<span>abc</span> Test"
```

Can I somehow disable the processing of my strings in ajax response?

Comment: Why, what for …?

Comment: It is a special case when I want to show an escaped string

Comment: use `dataType: "text"` instead of `json`

Comment: That would mean that I do not get an object back. Just simple text. I only want that the values of the object are not processed (unescaped)

Comment: @dare2k share your sever side code.

Comment: I would rather not, the important lines are var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml }; response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, settings));